# Is there any chance for get ng-boostrap popup modal as component and will get it from another component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-components, ng-bootstrap

I am using **[this modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)**  in my application, I have two components.

Parent Html:

```
<div id="list">
<ul><li class"list li><a id="modal1" (click) = "openmodal($event)"></a>
....
....
</div>
```

Parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildModalComponent } from 'src/app/popup-modal/popup-modal.component';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'parentcomp',
  templateUrl: './parentcomp.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parentcomp.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private loadComponent = false;
  closeResult: string;
  constructor(private modalService : NgbModal) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  openmodal(event) {
    alert("clicked!")
    //this.modalService = modalService;
    let component = new ChildModalComponent(modalService);
    //component.open("Hello");
    //this.modalService.open("Hello!!");
  }
}
```

Here when I opened `this.modalService.open("Hello!!")` - its open normal text popup without `ng-template`

Child Html:

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Child Components:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildModalComponent {
  closeResult: string;    
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

How to open `child.component.html` popup? And how to pass id or title when clicking on `openmodal($event)`?

output screen : [image: this.serviceModal.open("Hello")]
Code : [Editor Code](https://angular-8kbgbu.stackblitz.io)

Comment: You can use `@input` to trigger popup

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component holds the `ng-template` which wraps the child component that does not need to know anything about the modal.

The child component can have `@Input()` and `@Output()` bindings to pass data to it or interact with the parent from within the child (ie close the modal).

Rough Example:

Parent template

```
<ng-template #content let-modal let-inputData="inputData">
    <child-component
        [input]="inputData"
        (failed)="modal.dismiss()"
        (succeeded)="modal.dimiss()"
    />
</ng-template>

<button (click)="modalOpen(content)">Launch modal</button>
```

Parent class

```
....
modalOpen(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content)...
}
```

Child component does not need to implement any modal specific functionality.

**[UPDATE]**

As mentioned in the comments this particular example does not work because the component is Not part of the modules `entryComponents`. Additionally, the child component has no functionality programmed as it just has a ngtemplate defined in its template without any processing on it.

Comment: am not able do get popup window with your changes.. if i have used this.modalService.open("hello") , am able see small input type text only.. i have updated screenshot.

Comment: I can't tell without looking at the complete updated code. What is the error you are getting? For the start try having a simple template with a string and try to open that. ie: `<ng-template #content let-modal>Hello world.</ng-template>`. As mentioned this is the parent template, the child does not need to know about the modal...

Comment: please check this url for code - [editor code](https://angular-8kbgbu.stackblitz.io) && https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kbgbu

Comment: You need to add your component to the `entryComponents`. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfztkn  But I still think your approach is not good and you should go towards a solution like mentioned in my answer. Also, there is no need for instantiating the component before passing it to the modal service.

Comment: thanks, but my requirement is when click on button its should open popup modal(its separate component html), with your solution i got **"Hello world"** text popup **but not <ng-template #content let-modal>**

Comment: Your child component is not good. You just have a template that is not used anywhere. Also, there is code for opening another modal from within the child compoenent. This is definitely outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Anyway here is a working example based on your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcnayp but as mentioned I would **strongly suggest against this approach**.

Comment: No problem. If you think the answer helped to resolve the issue please mark it as accepted.